# Changing order of sha 256 update change the value

Tags: java, hash, sha, message-digest

if i creat a messagedigist then update it with bytes values, change order change the ouput of the hash

**Example**

```
    BigInteger d_KGC = new BigInteger("773182302672421767750165305491852205951657281488");
    BigInteger r_KGC = new BigInteger("1354751385705862203270732046669540660812388894970");
    String C_ID = "id_c";

    hash_h_c.update(r_KGC.toByteArray());
    hash_h_c.update(d_KGC.toByteArray());
    hash_h_c.update(C_ID.getBytes());
    BigInteger h_c = new BigInteger(1, hash_h_c.digest());
    System.out.println(h_c);
```

**output**

> 49379655005878985488511725474312101658690290667242109419474456484341588492679

But if I change the order of updates like:

```
    hash_h_c.update(d_KGC.toByteArray());
    hash_h_c.update(r_KGC.toByteArray());
    hash_h_c.update(C_ID.getBytes());
    BigInteger h_c = new BigInteger(1, hash_h_c.digest());
    System.out.println(h_c);
```

**output**

> 74931638923759682675388497216517269416730536285702508607436092426996570518730

**Isn't the overall result must be the same?
or changing order result in diffrent hash**

Comment: What makes you think that the order of updates is _not_ significant? If you concatenate three strings in different order, you'll get a different output, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a good thing if changing the order of input changes the hash value. Otherwise you'd run into issues where "bat" and "tab" both hashed to the same value, for example. For cryptographic hashes like SHA-256, the goal is to make it impossible (with a very large but not infinite amount of resources) to find any other input that produces the same hash value, and "bat" and "tab" are two different inputs, so it would be both surprising and unfortunate if they had the same hash value.